# Number of 6-person events so all groups of 3/10 people have dined together

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics, optimization

Assume 10 people numbered 1-10 have to be invited for dinner events. However, the hotel can accommodate only 6 at a time. Therefore, they will be invited in batches until all groups of 3 people have dined together. A person can be invited to more than 1 event.

What is the minimum number of such dinner events needed? What is an example arrangement that will work, and how can it be reached logically?

Here is an example of a simpler version with 4 people where 3 can dine at a time. To make sure every person has dined with every other, 3 events can be held as so:

- 1  2  3
- 1  2  4
- 1  3  4

I do know the **answer**  from the source below. However, I don't know how to reach this conclusion logically. I need the logic/formula to calculate it.
I tried brute force but I can't do in less events than stated below

> 10

**Event arrangement solution**

> 1  2  3  4  5  7
>
> 2  3  4  5  6  8
>
> 3  4  5  6  7  9
>
> 4  5  6  7  8 10
>
> 1  5  6  7  8  9
>
> 2  6  7  8  9 10
>
> 1  3  7  8  9 10
>
> 1  2  4  8  9 10
>
> 1  2  3  5  9 10
>
> 1  2  3  4  6 10

Source: similar problem that my friend has sent me
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/130488/combinatoric-puzzle-minimum-servings-at-dinner

Comment: Likely to be closed, lack of attribution.  But the answer is Combination(10,3)/ Combination(6,3) = 120/20=6.    
Which places this question purely in the Textbook Style Question realm

Comment: @ChrisCudmore that was my first calculation too. But I don't think that is correct. If you apply that to the simpler example I gave , you get 2 , but it is impossible to arrange in 2 events . Give it a try

Comment: @ChrisCudmore That calculation gives a lower bound, but it may not always be achievable to do it in so few rounds.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore That calculation provides only a lower bound.

Comment: Potentially, there's a nice graph theoretic interpretation for this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [La Jolla Covering Repository](https://ljcr.dmgordon.org/cover/table.html), your proposed solution is known to be optimal:
https://ljcr.dmgordon.org/cover/show_cover.php?v=10&k=6&t=3

"Method of Construction: cyclic covering found by search program"

Another approach is to use integer linear programming, with a binary decision variable $x_S$ for each $6$-subset $S \subset [10]$. The problem is to minimize $\sum_S x_S$ subject to
$$\sum_{S: T \subset S} x_S \ge 1 \quad \text{for all $3$-subsets $T \subset [10]$}$$

Comment: I do know that from the source my friend shared, but how do you come to conclusion, and how do you design the arrangement ?

Comment: "integer linear programming" is this something I can do manually and come to conclusion ?Sorry I am not aware of this. 
One more question that I had Rob is why is the minimum count not equal to C(10,3)/C(6,3) ,this has been driving me crazy for last 3 days. What am I missing ?

Comment: Except for very small instances, integer linear programming requires a solver.  The minimum does not match the lower bound because you cannot avoid duplicates, as you noted in a comment about $C(4,3,2)$.  Note also that the Schonheim inequality $C(v,k,t) \ge \lceil (v/k) C(v-1,k-1,t-1)\rceil $ implies $C(10,6,3) \ge \lceil (10/6) C(9,5,2) \rceil = \lceil (10/6) 5 \rceil= 9$.